# How do I make a screen reader focus on messages

Tags: html, xhtml, wai-aria

I am using aria for screen reader. How can I make the screen reader focus on the following error? I added `role ="error" tabindex="-1"` but doesn't focus when the error comes on.

```
<div role ="error" tabindex="-1" ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" ng-if="flash" ng-bind="flash.message" style="text-align:left;" class="ng-binding ng-scope alert alert-success">Item has been added to Shopiing cart</div>
```

Comment: The tag [tag:ada] is about the programming language Ada. I’m pretty sure you mean the Americans with Disabilities Act.

Comment: @SimonWright - yes that for american with disabilities.. i need to be able to focus on error messages inside a div or p tag etc

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of context for this but I would wonder if you really need to set focus.

If you do need to focus it is only possible with JavaScript .focus(). The tabindex added to it will mean when a focus is set that tab order is still maintained.

However, it looks like you are using this as a quick alert to let the user know if the item was added or not. It doesn't seem like there is a need for actual interaction/movement.

If you use focus you are potentially taking the user from their current place to a whole new area of the page. If there aren't next steps where they were jumped to the user may not be sure what to do next.

However, aria is understood by modern versions of screen readers and there is an aria-live attribute you can use. You can set it to polite so it waits for the user to finish their interaction first. I would also change your role to alert.

This approach allows for the user to keep interacting with the page but be alerted that something was successful or not.